# Período de dias entre duas datas, quando a data final é menor que a inicial

Tags: php, data

No PHP quando eu tento retornar os dias corridos de um mês eu apenas consigo os dias futuros:

```php
$inicio = new DateTime('2019-11-12'); 
$fim = clone $inicio;                   
$fim->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // intervalo de 1 mês

$intervaloPeriodo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'); // período de 1 dia
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio , $intervaloPeriodo, $fim);

foreach ($periodo as $p) {
    echo $p->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";    
}
```

O retorno do código acima são as datas no intervalo de 1 mês de forma crescente:

```php
/*
 data exemplo: 2019-11-12
- 2019-11-12
- 2019-11-13
- 2019-11-14
- 2019-11-15
 ... 
- 2019-12-11

*/
```

Porém o loop que eu preciso são os dias passados do mês em questão (decrescente):

```php
/*
 data exemplo: 2019-11-12
- 2019-11-12
- 2019-11-11
- 2019-11-10
- 2019-11-09
 ... 
- 2019-10-13

*/
```

O que acontece é que o período funciona apenas se for o período *positivo/posterior* mas eu preciso do período *negativo/anterior* do mês corrido.

Nota: setando o dia como -1 (`DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day')`)
não funciona, ele entra em um *loop* e não retorna o resultado esperado.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema ou outra forma de implementar esse período de datas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338289/4734177

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

`DatePeriod` tem um [construtor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) no qual, em vez da data final, você passa a quantidade de recorrências (ou seja, a quantidade de vezes que o intervalo será aplicado).

Então em vez de passar a data final, basta passar a quantidade de recorrências. Como estou aplicando um intervalo negativo de "menos 1 dia", a quantidade de recorrências será a quantidade de dias entre as datas inicial e final:

```
$inicio = new DateTime('2019-11-12');
$fim = clone $inicio;
$fim->modify('-1 month'); // 1 mês antes
$diff = $fim->diff($inicio); // diferença entre as datas

// intervalo de "menos 1 dia"
$intervalo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day');
// aplica o intervalo de "menos 1 dia"
// a quantidade de recorrências é o "número de dias entre as datas - 1"
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, $intervalo, $diff->days - 1);
foreach ($periodo as $p) {
    echo $p->format("Y-m-d") . "<br />";
}
```

Isso imprime as datas de 12/11/2019 até 13/10/2019 (se eu não subtrair 1 de `$diff->days`, será impresso também o dia 12/10/2019), em ordem decrescente:

```
2019-11-12
2019-11-11
2019-11-10
2019-11-09
...
2019-10-13
```

[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/pdhDP1) o código rodando.

---

Obs: eu usei o [método `diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) para calcular a diferença entre as datas, pois um mês pode ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, então dependendo das datas envolvidas, [a quantidade total de dias pode variar](https://ideone.com/ab1ydy).